# Optimization for getting amplitude of FFT results for real signals

Tags: signal-processing, fast-fourier-transform

I need to compute amplitude of FFT result for real signals, which means that I don't need the precise result of FFT or phase information of the result. So I think I don't need to implement the standard FFT for this purpose. Is this right? If so, how to do it?

Comment: The algorithm is the same for real signals or for the amplitude spectrum

Comment: Yes, this is a property for real signals. But I also mention that I only need the amplitude information, so I want to know what else can I do to optimize the algorithm.

Comment: Nothing, apply the standard FFT algorithm